# Why Nginx uses longPolling instead of serverSentEvents as transport when running SignalR 1.2 under Mono

Tags: nginx, mono, raspberry-pi, signalr

After months of googling and trial & error, I finally managed to get MVC3 WebApplication run under mono in a Raspberry Pi 2 machine.  I'm also able to get SignalR 1.2 work and the ChatHub example work (the example found in Microsoft's SignalR 1.x tutorial sites).

The web application can be run successfully using either xsp4 or Nginx (with fastcgi-mono-server4) as the web server.

However, I found out that when this application runs under xsp4 and browsed by chrome, it uses 'serverSentEvents' as the SignalR transport.  When it is run under Nginx + fastcgi-mono-server4, it always uses 'longPolling' instead.

Does anyone know how to configure Nginx so it uses 'serverSentEvents' instead of 'longPolling'?

Thnak you very much.